# How to change NumberDecimalSeparator to a dot in C# interpolated strings for non-english Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core, cultureinfo, string-interpolation, invariantculture

I have prepared a [C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qBohud) for my question, however it does not really show the actual problem and correctly uses dots as decimal separator in the interpolated double values (**UPDATED** with Tim's trick, thank you):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    readonly static (double lng, double lat)[] Locations = 
    {
        (10.757938, 52.437444),
        (10.764379, 52.437314),
        (10.770562, 52.439067),
        (10.773268, 52.436633),
    };
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        string lngLats = Locations.Aggregate(string.Empty, (str, next) => str + $"{next.Item1:F6},{next.Item2:F6};");
        Console.WriteLine($"lngLats: {lngLats}\n");
        
        double x = 12.3456;
        Console.WriteLine($"A double value: {x}\n");
    }
}
```

However, when I run the same code on my Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 computer, (set to English language, but German region) using Visual Studio 2022, then the decimal separator is a comma:

[image: screenshot VS 2022]

My question is: how to ensure that the decimal separator character is *always* a dot in the interpolated strings?

Comment: If you change your fiddle to include this as first line, you can reproduce it there too: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation uses the current culture. So you need a workaround with `double.ToString`:

```
double x = 12.3456;
string result = x.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine($"A double value: {result}\n");
```

Your modified fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTaONq

So string interpolation doesn't support a different culture. You *could* use `string.Format`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "A double value: {0}\n", x));
```

Comment: Sure Tim, I have seen the suggestion on `ToString` method while searching for a solution... but my question is if there is some trick to make the string interpolation always use a dot.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: nope. Then you need to use `String.Format`. Added that to my answer

Comment: Wouldn't it work to set the current Culture, though? Like in your comment to the question, @TimSchmelter, only set it to Invariant?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods: Sure, that would work. But it has more impact, OP just want to modify this single string and not change the culture.What is the benefit over simply using the right tool(`double.ToString`)?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would have some possibly unwanted side-effects...

Comment: Thank you, Tim. But I think anyone agrees, that the `Console.WriteLine(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "A double value: {0}\n", x));` is a horribly long code line for printing a very simple string...

Comment: An extension method is off the table?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: well, no need to use the full namespace, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is enough, but i agree that this is not so nice than using string interpolation. I would add another line for the double.ToString and then use it in the interpolated string. That makes it very clear and readable(also in the debugger). But if you like one-liners you can also use `x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in the string, so `Console.WriteLine($"A double value: {x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}\n");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the invariant culture like this

```cs
string result1 = FormattableString.Invariant($"lngLats: {lngLats}\n");
string result2 = FormattableString.Invariant($"A double value: {x}\n");
```

With a `using static System.FormattableString;` you can simplify the calls and of course you can integrate this with the console output:

```cs
string lngLats = Locations.Aggregate(
    string.Empty,
    (str, next) => str + Invariant($"{next.Item1:F6},{next.Item2:F6};")
);
Console.WriteLine($"lngLats: {lngLats}\n");

double x = 12.3456;
Console.WriteLine(Invariant($"A double value: {x}\n"));
```

See also:

- [FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableString) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant)
- [String interpolation using $ / Implicit conversions and how to specify IFormatProvider implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#implicit-conversions-and-how-to-specify-iformatprovider-implementation)

Comment: Again, a good suggestion (thank you, upvoted), but it does not suggest a method to fix the string interpolation `$".....{aNumber}..."`

Comment: Well, the same solution works for that one as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this compromise, maybe?

```
double x = 12.3456;
Console.WriteLine($"A double value: {x.AsInvariant()}\n");

// with

public static string AsInvariant(this double x) =>
   x.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You could simply use `$"A double value: {x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}\n"` which i like more, because everyone sees what it's doing.

Comment: While I agree, OP wanted something shorty short ... I don't think this will leave us with a clean _and_ satisfying answer, I am afraid.